# local image doesn't appear using require react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I tried to get dynamically the directory of the images using require but doesn't work

```
import React from 'react';
import './produto.css'


function Produto({data}) {

    const { id, name, price, score, image } = data;

    return <div className = 'produto-card-container' key = {id}>

        <div className = 'produto-card-flex'>
            <img alt = {image} src = {require(`../../Assets/${image}`)}/>
         
        </div>
    </div>
}

export default Produto;
```

but in my page the image appear likes this
[image]

i tried to console the path and the image name to see what's happened
My console log of the const image

```
super-mario-odyssey.png
produto.js:8 call-of-duty-infinite-warfare.png
produto.js:8 the-witcher-iii-wild-hunt.png
produto.js:8 call-of-duty-wwii.png
produto.js:8 mortal-kombat-xl.png
produto.js:8 shards-of-darkness.png
produto.js:8 terra-media-sombras-de-mordor.png
produto.js:8 fifa-18.png
produto.js:8 horizon-zero-dawn.png
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember "**require** returns an object and image's path can be ejected from its **default** property".

So you must change the following code:

```
<img alt = {image} src = {require(`../../Assets/${image}`)}/>
```

To :

```
<img alt={image} src={require(`../../Assets/${image}.png`).default}/>
```

**Note**: If you want to use multi image formats, add **imageFormat** key to your json db and pass it's value as props.

```
{
    ...
    image: 'assassins-creed',
    imageFormat : 'jpg'
}
```

So if you do that, your code must be like to:

```
const {id, name, price, score, image, imageFormat} = data;

<img alt={image} src={require(`../../Assets/${image}.${imageFormat}`).default}/>
```

Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

It's necessary to indicate the type of image. In your case, it is a png.

```
 <img alt = {image} src = {require(`../../Assets/${image}.png`)}/>
```

Comment: but in my json db the image is already saved as a png

Comment: I dont understand why if you have the image in /Assets/ location you need to search  to get dynamically the directory

Comment: I have a json db, with products, and the products have i index called 'image' where then have the image name, and the images file is saved in the assets folder

Comment: You can test to put all path C:/Asstest/.. where you have the images. I think that the sistem is showing and string and not a image